# How to print each object in a collection in a separate page in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, collections, printing, pagination

I would like to know if its possible to print each object in a collection in separate pages using Silverlight printing API.

Suppose I have a class `Label`

```
public class Label
{
    public string Address { get; set; }    
    public string Country { get; set; }    
    public string Name { get; set; }    
    public string Town { get; set; }
}
```

I can use print API and print like this.

```
private PrintDocument pd;

private void PrintButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   pd.Print("Test Print");
}

private void pd_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    Label labelToPrint = new Label() 
    { 
        Name = "Fake Name", Address = "Fake Address",
        Country = "Fake Country", Town = "Town"
    };

    var printpage = new LabelPrint();
    printpage.DataContext = new LabelPrintViewModel(labelToPrint);
    e.PageVisual = printpage;
}
```

**LabelPrint Xaml**

```
<StackPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot" VerticalAlignment="Center"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Address}" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Town}" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Country}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Now, say I've a collection of Label objects,

```
List<Label> labels = new List<Label>() 
{
    labelToPrint, labelToPrint, labelToPrint, labelToPrint
};
```

How can I print each object in the list in separate pages ?

Thanks for any suggestions ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a multi page printer.

```
private List<Label> printLabels;    
private PrintDocument pd;

private void PrintButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   // save the labels to a temporary list
   printLabels = new List<Label>(labels);

   // start the printing
   pd.Print("Test Print");
}

private void pd_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    // print the first element from the temporary list
    Label labelToPrint = printLabels.First();

    var printpage = new LabelPrint();
    printpage.DataContext = new LabelPrintViewModel(labelToPrint);
    e.PageVisual = printpage;

    printLabels.Remove(labelToPrint);

    // continue printing if there's still any labels left
    e.HasMorePages = printLabels.Any();
}
```